# 554 SMTP Mail Error Django

Tags: python, django, email, web-hosting, django-1.7

I've recently set up a Django 1.7.3 website on my Ubuntu 12.04 server using Apache and mod_wsgi. Everythink works fine except the mail sending. I don't understand why this does not work since I've been using the same configuration (port, host etc.) on a previous PHP website and that worked. So it must be something coming from Python. The code and email sending also worked locally.

In my `settings.py` file I have written my SMTP Hosting configuration :

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'SSL0.OVH.NET'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@mywebsite.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

And here is my Contact function :

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            recipients = ['contact@mywebsite.com']
            try:
                send_mail(subject,message,sender, recipients)
                return redirect('myapp:index')
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
    else: 
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

( I get the same error with `send_mail('hello','a simple text message', 'me@gmail.com', ['contact@mywebsite.com'])`)

**My error message:**

```
SMTPDataError at /contact/
    (554, b'mail server permanently rejected message (#5.3.0)')
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL: http://mywebsite.com/contact/
    Django Version: 1.7
    Exception Type: SMTPDataError
    Exception Value: (554, b'mail server permanently rejected message (#5.3.0)')
    Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.2/smtplib.py in sendmail, line 761
    Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
    Python Version:3.2.3
    Python Path:
    ['/opt/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py3.2.egg',
     '/opt/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip-1.1-py3.2.egg',
     '/var/www/mywebsite',
     '/opt/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python3.2/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python3.2',
     '/usr/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Thanks a lot for the help !

**UPDATE**
I've got successful results using gmail as a smtp server, so the problem is coming from OVH ? (but it is strange because with the same settings for the same OVH mail account, I have no problem with the PHP website on the same server). I've contacted them and will keep you updated.

Comment: This could be that your server is seeing the message as spam (ref: http://e-pyfan.com/content/SMTPDATAERROR1/en/).

Comment: Another setting to look into here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/Cy606otv3C0/ivb5Ws9yLqgJ

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking your hosts configuration for SMTP to ensure it isn't rejecting emails sent without a sender's address. If it is, you'll need to specify the sender in your `settings.py` or your function.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer and links, but I am sure there is an explicit sender with a valid email address.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was just google with some part of your error and got this please check out:

http://www.marshu.com/design-computer-tips-tricks-fixes-reason-554-mail-server-permanently-rejected-message-email-returned.php

and also check this:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/hM8C1wJXGCo

maybe this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the links, regarding the first : I'm not sending any file with this mail, it as simple as it can get. For the second one, this has confirmed the fact that the problem probably comes from OVH.  I've contacted them and will keep my post updated.